# How to use Blob in safari 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari, blob

Do safari browser for windows (version 5.1) support Blob?

The following sample code returns an error in console:

```
var array=[1,2];
var aBlob = new Blob( array);
```

Error:

> "'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
>   Blob( array)')"

How to fix this,If safari didn't support blob then how to replace this

Comment: `How to fix this,If safari didn't support blob then how to replace this` why array is not an option? why you even need blob?

Comment: [`BlobBuilder API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: @RayonDabre Hi sir,Thank You for your suggestion,
is BlobBuilder works,The documentation says it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.
Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob it is supported since Safari 6.

EDIT : obviously, MDN shows the way to use Blob without constructor:

```
var builder = new BlobBuilder();
var fileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
builder.append(fileParts[0]);
var myBlob = builder.getBlob('text/xml');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob
Basic Support is 8.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob 

Basic Support is 6

Which one is correct

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=Blob let's say... Safari 8. Anyway, you should use BlobBuilder if you need it for Safari. Safari 5 IS deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the [blob-polyfill](https://github.com/bjornstar/blob-polyfill) in your page and it will add `Blob` (and `new Blob(array)` constructor) support to older browsers.  It will construct Blobs using BlobBuilder when available.

Answer (score 1):

As Blobs are only supported by Safari 6+ you can try to use external library like [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js)

> Blob.js implements the W3C Blob interface in browsers that do not natively support it.